# How to Filter IShellFolder::EnumObjects result

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windows-shell

I am trying to create a shell tree control. I do not want all the items that return from `IShellFilder::EnumObjects` call to display on the tree as I need to filter items such as the Recycle Bin and the Control Panel for example.

My code looks like this:

```
IShellFolder* pDesktopFolder=NULL;
SHGetDesktopFolder(&pDesktopFolder);


LPITEMIDLIST pidlParent=NULL;
IShellFolder* pParentFolder = NULL;
pDesktopFolder->BindToObject(pidlParent,NULL, IID_IShellFolder, (LPVOID*)&pParentFolder);

IEnumIDList* pEnumIDList = NULL;
    SHCONTF SHFlag=NULL;
    SHFlag=SHCONTF_FOLDERS | SHCONTF_INIT_ON_FIRST_NEXT | SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS  | SHCONTF_INCLUDEHIDDEN;

HRESULT hr= pParentFolder->EnumObjects(NULL, SHFlag, &pEnumIDList);

if (NOERROR == hr)
{
     LPITEMIDLIST pidl = NULL, pidlAbs;
     CString csFileType;
     HTREEITEM hItem=NULL;
     while (NOERROR == pEnumIDList->Next(1, &pidl, NULL))
     {
        //Filter out control panel, recycle bin items and other non usable items
     }
}
```

I don't want to get the display name of each item and do a string comparison on that since names can change depending on the OS language.

Can the filtering be done based on the CLSID of each item? And whats the best way of doing it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved:

I did this and its working, yet I need to see where can I get a list of GUIDs for other folders:

```
ULONG nEaten=0;
    LPITEMIDLIST PidlCPanel;
    ULONG nCPAttrib = 0;
    HRESULT hr = pFolder->ParseDisplayName(NULL, NULL, _T("::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}"), &nEaten, &PidlCPanel, &nCPAttrib);
    BOOL bRes = ILIsEqual(pidl, PidlCPanel);
```

Comment: You are not supposed to use system folder GUIDs like that.  Use the `SHGetFolderLocation()` and/or `SHGetKnownFolderIDList()` functions to get `ITEMIDLIST`s for system folders, including the Recycle Bin (`CSIDL_BITBUCKET`/`FOLDERID_RecycleBinFolder`) and Control Panel (`CSIDL_CONTROLS`/`FOLDERID_ControlPanelFolder`).

Comment: can u post an answer about how to use these in my code context

Comment: Also bear in mind that SHGetKnownFolderIDList is not available for XP.

Answer (score 4):

When you have a IShellFolder and a child pidl you can use [`SHGetDataFromIDList(...,SHGDFIL_DESCRIPTIONID)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetdatafromidlista) to get the CLSID of the pidl target.

See also:

- [How can I tell that a directory is really a recycle bin?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080918-00/?p=20843)
- [How can I tell that a directory is weird and should be excluded from the user interface?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080919-00/?p=20833) (In your case, use the shell attributes and not the file attributes)

Answer (score 0):

It seems if you only want to have real Filesystem items (just like BrowseForFolder), then you can use `GetAttributesOf(..)` and check for `SFGAO_FILESYSANCESTOR`, if it doesn't have the attribute, it isn't a filesystem item.. (zip files, control panel, recyclebin don't have the attribute)

Comment: Hmm.. found out, that zipfiles aren't filtered (weird).. You'll have to check a zipfile on `SFGAO_BROWSABLE` too (so if it's `SFGA_FILESYSANCESTOR` and `SFGA_BROWSABLE` and maybe even check `SFGA_FILESYSTEM`. Checking `SFGA_STREAM` isn't a good idea, as on my system all folders under 'computer' and specific drives seem to have it set (Windows 7 x64 ultimate).

Comment: oh dear, just found out on Windows XP that `SFGA_BROWSABLE` can be a valid attribute for a folder, and zipfiles are not shown.. grrrr.. this is really annoying, next time MS how about making sure everything works the same on all platforms... So zipfiles (or .cab files), back to the drawingboard..