# Seeking correct CLSID for Control Panel

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to filter IShellFolder::EnumObjects result, by following instructions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966881/how-to-filter-ishellfolderenumobjects-result) question.

Although links from the highest voted answer are invalid, I was able to find them and apply Mr.Chen's code in my own. Everything worked fine for Recycle Bin, it was filtered out, but Control Panel stayed.

Below is the example code, with relevant comments. All I have changed was the constant `CLSID_RecycleBin` to `CLSID_ControlPanel`, everything else was the same.

```
 HRESULT CShellTree::EnumObjects(HTREEITEM hParentItem, LPSHELLFOLDER pParentFolder, LPITEMIDLIST pidlParent)
    {
        LPENUMIDLIST pEnum = NULL;

        HRESULT hr = pParentFolder->EnumObjects(NULL, m_dwFlags, &pEnum);
        if (FAILED(hr) || pEnum == NULL)
        {
            return hr;
        }

        LPITEMIDLIST pidlTemp;
        DWORD dwFetched = 1;
        LPAFX_SHELLITEMINFO pItem;

        while (SUCCEEDED(pEnum->Next(1, &pidlTemp, &dwFetched)) && dwFetched)
        {
            IShellFolder* psf;
            LPCITEMIDLIST pidlChild;
            bool skip = false;

            hr = SHBindToParent(pidlTemp, IID_IShellFolder, (void**)&psf, &pidlChild);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                SHDESCRIPTIONID pdid;
                hr = SHGetDataFromIDList(psf, pidlChild, SHGDFIL_DESCRIPTIONID, &pdid, sizeof(pdid));
                psf->Release();
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    // below comparison fails, but it works for CLSID_RecycleBin
                    // when going through Debugger, pdid.clsid is {26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}
                    // CLSID_ControlPanel is {21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}
                    skip = pdid.clsid == CLSID_ControlPanel;
                }
            }

            if (skip)
                continue;
            // insert TreeView item, omitted for brevity
        }
        return hr;
}
```

Going through the Debugger, I saw that `CLSID_ControlPanel` has the value `{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}` but code returns `{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}`, which is why comparison fails.

I have `F12`ed `CLSID_RecycleBin` hoping to find correct constant for Control Panel, but had no luck.

I have also looked [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/knownfolderid), but again had no success.

I have found [this link](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3123-clsid-key-guid-shortcuts-list-windows-10-a.html) but can not yet see how will this info help me.

I am currently going through [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14325953/why-would-the-pidl-for-the-control-panel-be-different) as it seems relevant...

### RELEVANT INFORMATION:

I am supporting Windows 8 onward, using VS 2019. For further info leave a comment.

### QUESTION:

How to make above CLSID comparison work? Where is the correct CLSID constant?

Comment: "*links from the highest voted answer are invalid*" - I have updated the links

Comment: The only documented one is {21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D} (CLSID_ControlPanel). {26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683} is  CLSID_ControlPanelCategory (https://www.magnumdb.com/search?q=%7B26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683%7D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Registry <sup>1</sup>, `{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}` is for the "Control Panel", whereas `{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}` is for "All Control Panel Items".

<sup>1: See the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}` and `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}` keys.</sup>

According to [Complete List of Windows 10 CLSID Key (GUID) Shortcuts](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3123-clsid-key-guid-shortcuts-list-windows-10-a.html):

```
Control Panel                           {5399E694-6CE5-4D6C-8FCE-1D8870FDCBA0}
Control Panel (All Tasks)               {ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}
Control Panel (always Category view)    {26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}
Control Panel (always Icons view)       {21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}
```

Same with [CLSID Key (GUID) Shortcuts List for Windows 7](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/110919-clsid-key-list-windows-7-a.html):

```
Control Panel                   {5399E694-6CE5-4D6C-8FCE-1D8870FDCBA0}
Control Panel (All Tasks)       {ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}
Control Panel (Category view)   {26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}
Control Panel (Icons view)      {21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}
```

According to the [Magic Number Database](https://www.magnumdb.com), these CLSIDs are labeled as follows:

```
{5399E694-6CE5-4D6C-8FCE-1D8870FDCBA0} = CLSID_ControlPanelRecent
{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C} = CLSID_ControlPanelTasks
{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683} = CLSID_ControlPanelCategory
{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D} = CLSID_ControlPanel
```

So, you are likely going to have to filter on all of them, eg:

```
// CLSID_ControlPanel is already defined in shlguid.h
DEFINE_GUID(CLSID_ControlPanelRecent, 0x5399E694, 0x6CE5, 0x4D6C, 0x8F, 0xCE, 0x1D, 0x88, 0x70, 0xFD, 0xCB, 0xA0);
DEFINE_GUID(CLSID_ControlPanelTasks, 0xED7BA470, 0x8E54, 0x465E, 0x82, 0x5C, 0x99, 0x71, 0x20, 0x43, 0xE0, 0x1C);
DEFINE_GUID(CLSID_ControlPanelCategory, 0x26EE0668, 0xA00A, 0x44D7, 0x93, 0x71, 0xBE, 0xB0, 0x64, 0xC9, 0x86, 0x83);

...

skip = (
    (pdid.clsid == CLSID_ControlPanel) ||
    (pdid.clsid == CLSID_ControlPanelRecent) ||
    (pdid.clsid == CLSID_ControlPanelTasks) ||
    (pdid.clsid == CLSID_ControlPanelCategory)
);
```

Comment: There's also CLSID_ControlPanelRecent. https://www.magnumdb.com/search?q=CLSID_ControlPanel*

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks, added